# $(window).on('scroll', function () when scroll to 50 %, i want to load few data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to load few data asap browser scrollbar travelling to 50 %

for what using jquery i wrote following funcation :

```
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
            alert("scrolling");
            if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).innerHeight() >= $(window)[0].scrollHeight * 0.5) {

                if (counter < modules.length) {
                    LoadData(modules[counter]);
                }
                counter += 1;
            }
        })
```

but it is not working, how can i fixed that?

anthor try i made it is :

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
                alert("you are at bottom");
            }
        });
```

but i dont want alert fired at bottom, just at 50%

Comment: Did you look to see where it is not working?

Comment: i guess, the if condition, i wrote it is not correct !

Comment: `console.log($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).innerHeight(), ">=",  $(window)[0].scrollHeight * 0.5)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To detect that scrolling has reached 50% of your page use:

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() >= ($(document).height() - $(window).height())*0.5){
```

For the rest we should know what's inside `LoadData(modules[counter]);`

http://jsfiddle.net/carlodurso/a5wmLzfm/